# How to show id of an object in listview if the adapter is of type object

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

So i have a class:

```
class student{
 public int id;
 public String name;
}
```

And then i have an adapterArray of student type and that adapter is passed to a list view. I want to know how could i make the listview show only name of the student.
Code:

```
ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_day_wise_expense);
ArrayAdapter<Student> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>( this,R.layout.increase_size_text, kids);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where kids is an array of objects of Student and list is my list view.
I want the list to show their names.

Comment: Use adapter.getItem(position) which should return your Student class. And then you can execute student.name or getName() on it.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://androhub.com/android-listview/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `toString` method in `Student` class.

```
class student{
    public int id;
    public String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to override getView()

```
    ArrayAdapter<Student> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>(this, R.layout.increase_size_text, kids){
        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView == null ?
                    super.getView(position, convertView, parent) : convertView;
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id./* PUT ID HERE */);
            tv.setText(getItem(position).name);
            return view;
        }
    };
```

and you don't need to create your own layout. This will work too:

```
    ArrayAdapter<Student> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, kids){
        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView == null ?
                    super.getView(position, convertView, parent) : convertView;
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setText(getItem(position).name);
            return view;
        }
    };
```

Comment: @pskink Depends on what you want toString() to do. Sometimes it's preferable for toString() to actually print out all variables. Many times you also don't have access to the class as well.